# How can we send email to based on select option

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, codeigniter

I have one registration form. In ths form if I select one Journal the mail will comes to particular journal mail id and to register as well

Example:

Journal: Chemistry and Biochemistry

Mail Id: chemistry@gmail.com

If I select some another journal then the mail will go to particular email id. Please help me in this task. I tried but its not working. Can you see in image what is my question exactly?

[This is image of view page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNiim.jpg)

```js
Ajax Code


function registerNoaUser()
{
 var noaTxtRegFirstName   = $('#noaTxtRegFirstName').val().trim();
 var noaTxtRegLastName   = $('#noaTxtRegLastName').val().trim(); 
 var noaTxtRegEmail    = $('#noaTxtRegEmail').val().trim(); 
 var noaTxtRegPass    = $('#noaTxtRegPass').val().trim();
 var noaTxtRegConfPass   = $('#noaTxtRegConfPass').val().trim();
 var noaTxtRegAfflUniv   = $('#noaTxtRegAfflUniv').val().trim();
 var noaTxtRegCountry   = $('#noaTxtRegCountry').val().trim();
 var journal     = $('#journal').val().trim();
 var noaTxtUserType    =  $("input[name='noaUserType']:checked"). val();
 var regexPattern = /[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$/;
 
 var userfile   = $('#userfile').val();

 var regx            = /[A-Za-z]/;
 
 var flag = true;
 if( noaTxtUserType == 4)
 {
  if(journal == 0)
  {
   $('#jrnoul_error').html('Please Select Journal.').css('color','red');
   flag = false;
  }else{
   $('#jrnoul_error').html('');
  }
  
 }
 else{
   $('#jrnoul_error').html('');
  }
 if( noaTxtRegFirstName == "" )
 {
  $('#fname_error').html('Please enter First Name.').css('color','red');
  flag = false;
 }
 else if( ! noaTxtRegFirstName.match(regx) )
 {
  $('#fname_error').html('Please enter Charecters Only.').css('color','red');
  flag = false;
 }
 else
 {
  $('#fname_error').html('');
 }
 /* if( noaTxtRegLastName == "" )
 {
  $('#lname_error').html('Please enter Last Name.').css('color','red');
  flag = false;
 }
    else if( !noaTxtRegLastName.match(regx) )
 {
  $('#lname_error').html('Please Enter Charecters Only.').css('color','red');
  flag = false;
 }
 else
 {
  $('#lname_error').html('');
 } */
 if( noaTxtRegEmail == "" )
 {
  $('#email_error').html('Please enter Your Email.').css('color','red');
  flag = false;
 }
 else if(!noaTxtRegEmail.match(regexPattern))
 {
  $('#email_error').html('Please enter valid Email.').css('color','red');
  flag = false;
 }
 else
 {
  $('#email_error').html('');
 }

 if( noaTxtRegPass == "" )
 {
  $('#pass_error').html('Please enter Your Password.').css('color','red');
  flag = false;
 }
 else
 {
  $('#pass_error').html('');
 }

 if( noaTxtRegConfPass == "" )
 {
  $('#cnf_pass_error').html('Please Confirm Your Password.').css('color','red');
  flag = false;
 }
 else if( noaTxtRegPass != noaTxtRegConfPass )
 {
  $('#cnf_pass_error').html('Please enter Password and Confirm Password as same.').css('color','red');
  flag = false;
 }
 else
 {
  $('#cnf_pass_error').html('');
 }
 
 if( noaTxtRegAfflUniv == "" )
 {
  $('#affluniv_error').html('Please enter Affiliated University.').css('color','red');
  flag = false;
 }
    else if( !noaTxtRegAfflUniv.match(regx) )
 {
  $('#affluniv_error').html('Please Enter Charecters Only.').css('color','red');
  flag = false;
 }
 else
 {
  $('#affluniv_error').html('');
 }

 if( noaTxtRegCountry == "" )
 {
  $('#country_error').html('Please enter Country.').css('color','red');
  flag = false;
 }
    else if( !noaTxtRegCountry.match(regx) )
 {
  $('#country_error').html('Please Enter Charecters Only.').css('color','red');
  flag = false;
 }
 else
 {
  $('#country_error').html('');
 }
 
 if( flag == true )
 {
  var filesNotGiven = false;
  $("input[id^='noaRegnFile_']").each(function()
  {
   var textboxId = parseInt(this.id.replace("noaRegnFile_", ""));
   userfile = $('#noaRegnFile_'+textboxId).val()
   if( userfile != "" )
   {
    filesNotGiven = true;
    return;
   }
  });
  if( ! filesNotGiven )
  {
   alert( "Please upload 1 or more files." );
   flag = false;
  }else 
  {
   $("input[id^='noaRegnFile_']").each(function()
   {
    var textboxId = parseInt(this.id.replace("noaRegnFile_", ""));
    userfile = $('#noaRegnFile_'+textboxId).val()
    
   });
   var ext = userfile.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
   if($.inArray(ext, ['pdf','doc','docx','png','jpg','jpeg','csv']) == -1) {
    alert('alowed types png,jpg,pdf,doc only.');
    flag = false;
   }
  }
 }
 
 if( flag == true )
 {
  $('#noaRegnMsg').html( "Checking if Email Exists..." );

  $.ajax
  ({
   type :  "POST",
   cache : false,
   url  :  baseUrl+'Login/noaChkEmailExists',
   data : {noaTxtRegEmail:noaTxtRegEmail},
   success :  function(existsResult)
   {
    if( existsResult > 0 )
    {
     $('#noaRegnMsg').html( "Email already exists..." );
     return false;
    }
    else
    {
     $('#noaRegnMsg').html( "Email available..." );
     $('#noaFrmMainRegister').submit();
    }
   } 
  });
 }
}
```

```css
Controller



public function register()
 {
  $data = array();
  $data['menu'] = $this->load->view('common/menu', NULL, TRUE);
  $data['journal_details'] = $this->Login_model->getJournals();
  if( isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST) )
  {
   // echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST);
   // echo '<pre>';print_r($_FILES);
   // exit;

   $noaUserId = $this->registerUser( $_POST,$_FILES );
   // echo $d;exit;
   if( $noaUserId )
   {
    $naoUType = 0;
    if( isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['noaUserType']) )
    {
     $naoUType = $_POST['noaUserType'];
    }
    $noaRegFlashMsg = "You have Sucessfully Registered";
    if( $naoUType == 3 )
    {
     $noaRegFlashMsg .= " as Contributor.";
    }
    else if( $naoUType == 4 )
    {
     $noaRegFlashMsg .= " as Editor.";
    }
    else
    {
     $noaRegFlashMsg .= ".";
    }
    
    //email for registration
    
    $this->load->library('email'); 
    
    $config = Array(
     'protocol' =>'sendmail',
     'mailtype' => 'html',
     'newline' => '\r\n',
     'charset' => 'utf-8' 
    );
    $information = Array();
    $information['noaTxtRegFirstName']  = $_POST['noaTxtRegFirstName'];
    $information['noaTxtRegLastName']  = $_POST['noaTxtRegLastName'];
    $information['noaTxtRegEmail']   = $_POST['noaTxtRegEmail'];
    $information['noaTxtRegAfflUniv']  = $_POST['noaTxtRegAfflUniv'];
    $information['noaTxtRegPass']   = $_POST['noaTxtRegPass'];
    $information['noaTxtRegCountry']  = $_POST['noaTxtRegCountry'];
    $information['noaUserType']   = $_POST['noaUserType'];
    $information['designation']   = $_POST['designation'];
    $information['department']    = $_POST['department'];
    $journal_name       = $this->Login_model->noaGetJournalName($_POST['journal']);
    if(isset($journal_name->j_title) && $journal_name->j_title != ""){
     $information['journal_name']   = $journal_name->j_title;
    }else{
     $information['journal_name']   = '';
    }
  
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $from_email = 'example.contact@gmail.com';
    $to_email  = 'example.contact@gmail.com';
    $this->email->from($from_email, 'example'); 
    $this->email->to($to_email);
   
    $this->email->subject('Registration Mail');
    $message = $this->load->view('mail_templates/registration-mail', $information, TRUE);
    foreach($_FILES['noaRegnFiles']['name'] as $filename){
     
     $tempfilee     =  $filename;
     $name = date('Ymd') ."_". date("His");
     $expldedVal = explode('.',$tempfilee);
     $extension   =  strtolower(end($expldedVal));
   
     $upfileName   = $expldedVal[0].'_'.$name.'.'.$extension;
     $this->email->attach(''.base_url().'uploads/'.$noaUserId.'/'.$upfileName.'');
    }    
    $this->email->message($message); 
    $this->email->send();
    //sending mail to registered user
    $this->email->clear(TRUE); 
    
    $from_emaill  = 'example.contact@gmail.com';
    $to_emaill   = $_POST['noaTxtRegEmail'];
    $this->email->from($from_emaill, 'Register'); 
    $this->email->to($to_emaill);
    $this->email->subject('Registration Successfull');
    $messagee = $this->load->view('mail_templates/registration-success-mail', $information, TRUE);
    $this->email->message($messagee); 
    $this->email->send();
    
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message',$noaRegFlashMsg); 
    $this->show('register',$data);
   }
  }
  else
  {
   $this->show('register',$data);
  }

 }
```

```html
VieW Code
  


<div class="form-group" id="ed_journal" style="display:none;"><label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Journal<sup style="color:red">*</sup></label>
<div class="col-sm-7">
<select id="journal" class="form-control" name="journal"><option value="0">--Select Journal --</option>
<?php
if(isset($journal_details) && count($journal_details) > 0)
{
foreach($journal_details as $j_details){?>
<option value="<?php echo $j_details->j_id; ?>"><?php echo $j_details->j_title; ?></option>
<?php }
}
?>
</select>
<p id="jrnoul_error"></p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="ed_desg" style="display:none;">
<label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Designation</label>
<div class="col-sm-7">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="designation" name="designation" placeholder="Designation">
<p id="desg_error"></p>
</div>
</div>
 <div class="form-group" id="ed_dept" style="display:none;">
<label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Department</label>
<div class="col-sm-7">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="department" name="department" placeholder="Department">
<p id="dept_error"></p>
</div>
</div>
<span id="noaSpanRegFileDivs">
<div id="noaDivRegFile_1" class="form-group">
 <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Upload <span id="uploadtext">File</span><sup style="color:red">*</sup></label>
 <div class="col-sm-7 pos_r">
<input type="file" name="noaRegnFiles[]" class="form-control" id="noaRegnFile_0" style="height:auto;">
         <div class="Addfile"><a href="Javascript:void(0);" id="noaBtnRegnFile_1" OnClick="noaRegnAddIFile(1);" class="btn btn-warning">Add File</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</span>
       
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-10">
<button id="noaBtnMainRegsiter" type="button" onClick="registerNoaUser();" class="btn btn-warning">REGISTER</button>
<p id="noaRegnMsg" style="text-align:center;color:red"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How many email or journal in there? is the email obtained from database? you could do conditional checking on backend to match which journal corresponding to which email

Comment: 20 journals . each journals have separate mail

Comment: could you show how you provide the email data?

Comment: i am new to codeigniter.  Can you give brief explanation? This is very important to me. Please help me out from this

Comment: Please Can you check in controller file. provided the email data in controller

Comment: on the controller, it's expecting an email from the view, but there's no email data on the view, but I think you should provide the email data on the controller because it has nothing to do with the view. So you could compare the journal id and the email on the backend. Are you storing the email data on database?

Comment: we do not store email data on database

Comment: if($categoryinfo == "article title"){
               
$this->email->to('info@gmail.com');
          
}
else if($categoryinfo == "article title 2")
           {
               $this->email->to(info2@gmail.com);
           }
else if($categoryinfo == "article title 2")
           {
               $this->email->to(info3@gmail.com);
           }

Answer (score 1):

You could add a static conditional for the additional recipient on the controller, like this :

```
public function register()
{
    $data = array();
    $data['menu'] = $this->load->view('common/menu', NULL, TRUE);
    $data['journal_details'] = $this->Login_model->getJournals();
    if( isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST) )
    {
        // echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST);
        // echo '<pre>';print_r($_FILES);
        // exit;

        $noaUserId = $this->registerUser( $_POST,$_FILES );
        // echo $d;exit;
        if( $noaUserId )
        {
            $naoUType = 0;
            if( isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['noaUserType']) )
            {
                $naoUType = $_POST['noaUserType'];
            }
            $noaRegFlashMsg = "You have Sucessfully Registered";
            if( $naoUType == 3 )
            {
                $noaRegFlashMsg .= " as Contributor.";
            }
            else if( $naoUType == 4 )
            {
                $noaRegFlashMsg .= " as Editor.";
            }
            else
            {
                $noaRegFlashMsg .= ".";
            }

            //email for registration

            $this->load->library('email'); 

            $config = Array(
                'protocol' =>'sendmail',
                'mailtype' => 'html',
                'newline' => '\r\n',
                'charset' => 'utf-8' 
            );
            $information = Array();
            $information['noaTxtRegFirstName']  = $_POST['noaTxtRegFirstName'];
            $information['noaTxtRegLastName']   = $_POST['noaTxtRegLastName'];
            $information['noaTxtRegEmail']      = $_POST['noaTxtRegEmail'];
            $information['noaTxtRegAfflUniv']   = $_POST['noaTxtRegAfflUniv'];
            $information['noaTxtRegPass']       = $_POST['noaTxtRegPass'];
            $information['noaTxtRegCountry']    = $_POST['noaTxtRegCountry'];
            $information['noaUserType']         = $_POST['noaUserType'];
            $information['designation']         = $_POST['designation'];
            $information['department']          = $_POST['department'];
            $journal_name                       = $this->Login_model->noaGetJournalName($_POST['journal']);
            if(isset($journal_name->j_title) && $journal_name->j_title != ""){
                $information['journal_name']        = $journal_name->j_title;
            }else{
                $information['journal_name']        = '';
            }

            $this->email->initialize($config);
            $from_email = 'example.contact@gmail.com';
            $to_email   = 'example.contact@gmail.com';
            $this->email->from($from_email, 'example'); 
            $this->email->to($to_email);

            $this->email->subject('Registration Mail');
            $message = $this->load->view('mail_templates/registration-mail', $information, TRUE);
            foreach($_FILES['noaRegnFiles']['name'] as $filename){

                $tempfilee              =   $filename;
                $name = date('Ymd') ."_". date("His");
                $expldedVal = explode('.',$tempfilee);
                $extension      =   strtolower(end($expldedVal));

                $upfileName         = $expldedVal[0].'_'.$name.'.'.$extension;
                $this->email->attach(''.base_url().'uploads/'.$noaUserId.'/'.$upfileName.'');
            }               
            $this->email->message($message); 
            $this->email->send();
            //sending mail to registered user
            $this->email->clear(TRUE); 

            $from_emaill    = 'example.contact@gmail.com';
            $to_emaill      = $_POST['noaTxtRegEmail'];
            // add a conditional on secondary email recipient depends on journal id
            switch ($_POST['journal']) {
                case '1': // journal id
                    $to_emaill .= ', chemistry@gmail.com'; // recipient email
                    break;

                case '2':
                    $to_emaill .= ', email_2@domain.com';
                    break;

                case '3':
                    $to_emaill .= ', email_3@domain.com';
                    break;

                case '4':
                    $to_emaill .= ', email_4@domain.com';
                    break;

                default:
                    // default email recipient
                    $to_emaill .= ', email@domain.com';
                    break;
            }
            $this->email->from($from_emaill, 'Register'); 
            $this->email->to($to_emaill); // appended additional recipient, this will become : 'user@domain.com, chemistry@gmail.com'
            $this->email->subject('Registration Successfull');
            $messagee = $this->load->view('mail_templates/registration-success-mail', $information, TRUE);
            $this->email->message($messagee); 
            $this->email->send();

            $this->session->set_flashdata('message',$noaRegFlashMsg); 
            $this->show('register',$data);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->show('register',$data);
    }

}
```